# Change text update cancel buttons grid in sencha architect (ext js)

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

Just as the title says, is there any way to change the text (or languaje) of the update and cancel buttons while editing a grid?

Thanks,

Edit:

I already changed the text inside RowEditor.js

```
saveBtnText: 'Update',
```

to

```
saveBtnText: 'Example',
```

but doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `Ext.grid.RowEditor` class like so:

```
Ext.define(null, {
    override: 'Ext.grid.RowEditor',
    saveBtnText: 'Salveaza',
    cancelBtnText: 'Anuleaza'
});
```

Here is the working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27uj.

Assuming that you want to localize your entire application, you should take a looke at [this guide](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/core_concepts/localization.html#core_concepts-_-localization_-_localization_with_sencha_cmd) from sencha. Basically, you just require the `ext-locale` package in your `app.json`

```
"requires": [
    "ext-locale"
]
```

After this, you should set the `locale` param (also in `app.json`) to the desired language:

```
"locale": "es"
```

Doing this, you will get all ExtJS components localized.

Comment: I already changed the languaje using your method, but the buttons remain the same. However the override method works great, thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Did you run `sencha app refresh` after changing the language?

Comment: No, but I think that doesn't matter because other things like errors changed the languaje. It was just the grid buttons.